# Can you refer to the same recursive query twice?

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, recursive-query

I'm trying to recursively delete a folder and I've got this script:

```sql
with recursive all_folders (id) as (
    select f.id
    from folder f
    where f.id = 33

    union all

    select f.id
    from folder f
             join all_folders of on of.id = f.parent_folder_id
)
delete
from sample
where sample.parent_folder_id in (select id from all_folders);

with recursive all_folders (id) as (
    select f.id
    from folder f
    where f.id = 33

    union all

    select f.id
    from folder f
             join all_folders of on of.id = f.parent_folder_id
)
delete
from folder
where folder.id in (select id from all_folders);
```

---

I was wondering if I can clean up this duplication, by referring to a single `all_folders` result - rather than generating it twice.

I was also wondering if this query is inefficient - or can be improved.

Any thoughts?

Comment: No. But... you can actually refer to the same recursive CTE multiple times **in the same query**. In your case, however, you have two separate queries, so the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the same CTE in several queries, the likelihood is high that the best solution is a temporary table. You fill it with the result from the CTE and use it in several queries.

For example:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE allfolders (
   id bigint  -- I hope
);

with recursive all_folders (id) as (
    select f.id
    from folder f
    where f.id = 33

    union all

    select f.id
    from folder f
             join all_folders of on of.id = f.parent_folder_id
)
INSERT INTO allfolders (id)
SELEST id FROM allfolders;

delete
from sample
where sample.parent_folder_id in (select id from allfolders);

delete
from folder
where folder.id in (select id from allfolders);

DROP TABLE allfolders;
```

Comment: How does that look?

Comment: Added some sample code.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Should this really be more performant than duplicating the CTE? I'll try benchmarking when I get the time

Comment: You were asking how to avoid the repetition... but it might also be faster.